# How should I call non-database models?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, orm

Let's say I have a web application for computing complex matrix operations. The application also allows for user interaction. So my application consists of:

ORM models that map to database tables:

1. Users
2. Comments
3. History (of requested operations)

But also, there are some other classes that are used for:

1. Computing basic operations, such as multiplication, sum, etc.
2. A matrix class.
3. A matrix inverter.
4. A class that computes graphic processing operations using matrices.

So, in most web apps, people think of 'models' only as the ones that map to something in the database. But originally, the term model also refers to anything that's part of the logic of the app.

As far as I know, the first type of model I mentioned, would be the 'domain' model. (I'm not sure about this, so feel free to correct). But the second one, what's its name?

Answer (score 0):

To me 1st one is a *data model* having *entities* `User`, `Comment`, `History`. Yes all singular! Because table name should represent individual object that it stores so that when mapped using ORM, whole table set can be mapped as `Collection<User> Users`.

2nd one is the *domain layer* that does not know about data persistence and has everything that your app logic needs. So I would call `Matrix` class a *domain object* and just one `MatrixService` that does basic ops like multiplication, sum, inversion etc. on `Matrix` instance passed to it.

Since MVC is in the tag list, I would like to add that M (Model) in MVC is conceptual term and you need not really name anything as Model/Models. You can/should separate this M part as separate libraries and call them {app}.domain, {app}.data, {app}.services so on. They all together will represent M in MVC and do everything that Controller should not be doing.